# Comparing variables with values in another dataframe and replace them with another value

Tags: r

I have a Data.Frame with:

```
Height <- c(169,176,173,172,176,158,168,162,178)
```

and another with reference heights and weights.

```
heights_f <- c(144.8,147.3,149.9,152.4,154.9,157.5,160,162.6,165.1,167.6,170.2,172.7,175.3,177.8,180.3,182.9,185.4,188,190.5,193,195.6)
weights_f <- c(38.6,40.9,43.1,45.4,47.7,49.9,52.2,54.5,56.8,59,61.3,63.6,65.8,68.1,70.4,72.6,74.9,77.2,79.5,81.7,84)
weightfactor_f <- data.frame(heights_f, weights_f)
```

I now need to match the values of the heights from the first data.frame with the height reference in the second one that's the most fitting and to give me the correspondent reference weight.

I haven't yet had any success, as I haven't been able to find anything about matching values that are not exactly the same.

Comment: Please use a reproducible example i.e. remove the `...`

Comment: have you tried something like `which.min(abs(x - a)) ` where `x` is the vector and `a` is the number you're finding a match for?

Comment: Can you please add your desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your goal, instead of taking the nearest value, consider [interpolating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) through the `approx` function. For instance:

```
approx(weightfactor_f$heights_f,weightfactor_f$weights_f,xout=Height)$y
#[1] 60.23846 66.44400 63.85385 62.95600 66.44400 50.36000 59.35385 53.96923
#[9] 68.28400
```

Comment: What kind of sorcery is this!! o_O

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
Height<- c(169,176,173,172,176,158,168,162,178)
heights_f<- as.numeric(c(144.8,147.3,149.9,152.4,154.9,157.5,160,162.6,165.1,167.6,170.2,172.7,175.3,177.8,180.3,182.9,185.4,188,190.5,193,195.6)) 
weights_f<- as.numeric(c(38.6,40.9,43.1,45.4,47.7,49.9,52.2,54.5,56.8,59,61.3,63.6,65.8,68.1,70.4,72.6,74.9,77.2,79.5,81.7,84)) 

df = data.frame(Height=Height, match_weight=
          sapply(Height, function(x) {weights_f[which.min(abs(heights_f-x))]}))
```

i.e. for each entry in `Height`, find the corresponding element in the heights_f vector by doing `which.min(abs(heights_f-x)` and fetch the corresponding entry from the `weights_f` vector.

---

Output:

```
  Height match_weight
1    169         61.3
2    176         65.8
3    173         63.6
4    172         63.6
5    176         65.8
6    158         49.9
7    168         59.0
8    162         54.5
9    178         68.1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
```

Slightly different structure to reproducible example:

```
Height <- data.frame(height = as.numeric(c(169,176,173,172,176,158,168,162,178)))
```

The rest is the same:

```
heights_f<- as.numeric(c(144.8,147.3,149.9,152.4,154.9,157.5,160,162.6,165.1,167.6,170.2,172.7,175.3,177.8,180.3,182.9,185.4,188,190.5,193,195.6)) 
weights_f<- as.numeric(c(38.6,40.9,43.1,45.4,47.7,49.9,52.2,54.5,56.8,59,61.3,63.6,65.8,68.1,70.4,72.6,74.9,77.2,79.5,81.7,84)) 
weightfactor_f<- data.frame(heights_f,weights_f)
```

Then, round to the nearest whole number:

```
weightfactor_f$heights_f <- round(weightfactor_f$heights_f, 0)
```

Then just:

```
left_join(Height, weightfactor_f, by = c("height" = "heights_f"))
```

Output:

```
  height weights_f
1    169        NA
2    176        NA
3    173      63.6
4    172        NA
5    176        NA
6    158      49.9
7    168      59.0
8    162        NA
9    178      68.1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
z <- vector()
for(i in 1:length(Height)) {
z[i] <- weightfactor_f$weights_f[which.min(abs(Height[i]-weightfactor_f$heights_f))]
}
```